# Return columns, unique value count for df.nunique() values > 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abbbcdee'),
             'B': list(range(0,8)),
             'C': list('aaaaaaaa')})


    A   B   C
0   a   0   a
1   b   1   a
2   b   2   a
3   b   3   a
4   c   4   a
5   d   5   a
6   e   6   a
7   e   7   a
```

I would like to be able to filter the results of `df.nunique()` to only return values greater than 1.
`df.nunique()` returns:

```
df.nunique()
A    5
B    8
C    1
dtype: int64
```

I would like the following results:

```
A    5
B    8
dtype: int64
```

I expected this to work, but it doesn't:

```
df.loc[df.nunique() > 1]
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Comment: `df.nunique()[df.nunique()>1]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to slice your output with a self-reference, you could use an assignment expression (python ≥ 3.8):

For example:

```
s = (s:=df.nunique())[s.gt(1)]
```

or, more classically:

```
s = df.nunique()
s = s[s.gt(1)]
```

Output:

```
A    5
B    8
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter your result with a lambda function:

```
>>> df.nunique()[lambda x: x > 1]
A    5
B    8
dtype: int64
```